# Webpack bundle non-module JS in TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a project where I need to bundle 2 non-module JS files. These files unfortunately cannot easily be made into a module because they are used elsewhere as well.
There is a solution for these things in the form of 'script-loader' but that requires an import statement in a js file.
My big problem now is that the .ts entry file does not know about the 'script-loader' and tries to load the files and then complains that they don't have a declaration file for that 'module'.

This is my config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.\/bower_components\/something\/foo\.js$/,
        use: [ 'script-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },

    ]
```

And this is how I try to define the import of the two files:

```
import exec from '../bower_components/something/foo.js';
import exec2 from '../bower_components/someotherthing/bar.js';
```

Comment: I guess they should be externals and then imported manually as `<script src=""`

Comment: ok, that is how we do it now but my preferred end result would be to have one file we can deploy instead of 3

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas to get rid of the TypeScript errors:

- Suppress them with `// @ts-ignore`.
- Put your imports in a JavaScript file instead of a TypeScript file so the TypeScript compiler doesn't look at them.